# In JQuery, how to get iOS's fast scroll effect

Tags: jquery, ios, scroll

It is like a big swipe makes fast scroll over a big distance on view and then slowly stop. I want to make a web page that can provide this effect on a big div using jQuery. The page will be displayed on iPhone using a single web view. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need jQuery? You can achieve this effect with CSS:        `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

Comment: Andrew, thanks a lot! It seems what i will need :-)

Comment: Yes, it worked. My follow-up question: does the touchMove event always trigger an scroll event? Do I have to handle them separately?